# Why fragment based viewPager.setCurrentItem is not working inside an adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a fragment in MainActivity that handles other fragments inside a view page.
This is that one:

```
class FragOrdersHolder : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_holder_frg, container, false)
        return mainView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(mainView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(mainView, savedInstanceState)

        viewPager = mainView.findViewById(R.id.ordersViewPagerID)

        viewPager.adapter = OrdersPagerAdapter(activity!!.supportFragmentManager)

        val pagerTab = mainView.findViewById<PagerTabStrip>(R.id.pagerHeaderID)
        pagerTab.tabIndicatorColor = Color.WHITE
        pagerTab.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    }

    fun GoTo(pos: Int) {
        Handler().post(Runnable {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true)
        })
    }
}
```

---

I have 3 fragments in my viewPager and one of them, have a recyclerview inside it.

the recyclerview has a custom adapter class.

I want to go to next tap in viewPager when clicking on an item in the recylerview.

I'm calling the GoTo method in adapter class like this:

```
val fm = (activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
val fragm = fm.findFragmentByTag("HOLDER") as FragOrdersHolder
fragm.GoTo(2)
```

I'd tried everything viewPager.setCurrentItem not working!
please help me.

Comment: Is your click listener and `GoTo` actually called?

Comment: @tynn yes. It get calls. When I trace it by line by line it works prefect! The GoTo() always called but nothing work unless when debugging step by step!